# DataGrip - exception when creating MySql connection

Tags: datagrip

Error:

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 184 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 169 milliseconds ago.
> java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly.

But, I changed to another tool like DBaver and can successfully create the connection:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btz1J.png)

Comment: Don't you need to enable SSL?

Comment: Not needed.....

Comment: Did you change anything in SSL tab? 
Also, exception says, that you may use wrong TLS version